# AngularJS tdd with Jasmine error: Cannot read property '$injector' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd, jasmine, inject

I have these TypeError:
- Cannot read property '$injector' of undefined
- Cannot read property '$modules' of undefined
- Cannot call method 'selPersonToChange' of undefined

files included in jasmine html page stand alone:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

  <script src="../../angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../form-input/script.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../form-input/tdd.js"></script>
```

jasmine script:

```
describe("myApp", function(){

    beforeEach(module("mymod"));

    describe("maincontroller", function(){

        var scope;
        var ctrl;
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller("maincontroller", {$scope:scope});    
        }));

        it("select person", function(){
             a = scope.selPersonToChange();
             expect(a).toEqual(true);     
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried testing with the non-minified version of Angular?

Comment: no, should I have do that?

Comment: I haven't tried testing with the minified version, but since you are using an injectable function in the test, you might need to call it with the minified form, i.e. inject(['param1', function(param1){}]);

Comment: Which version of angular are you using??

Comment: Angular the last one, and Jasmine 2

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, using non-minified angular and angular-mocks 1.3.0 solved it for me.